# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 11) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have the following model:

```
Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_9 (Dense)              (None, 256)               10496     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_9 (Activation)    (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_6 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_10 (Dense)             (None, 256)               65792     
_________________________________________________________________
activation_10 (Activation)   (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)          (None, 256)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_11 (Dense)             (None, 11)                2827      
_________________________________________________________________
activation_11 (Activation)   (None, 11)                0         
=================================================================
Total params: 79,115
Trainable params: 79,115
Non-trainable params: 0
```

With the following inputs/labels:

```
x_train: (100, 40)
y_train: (100,)
```

I take in audio files, convert to a 40-long MFCC feature vector. I have 100 examples. That's where I get the (100, 40). The labels (100 of them, one for each example) are all strings, and there are 11 classifications.

I followed a tutorial and used this to build a model:

```
def build_model(feat_len, out_len):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(keras.Input(shape=(feat_len,)))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(256))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(out_len))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer='adam')
    return model
```

For the input, I am using `feat_len = 40` (the number of MFCC features).
For the output dense layer, I'm using `out_len = len(labels) = 11`.

However, when trying to run

```
score = model.evaluate(x_train, y_train, verbose=0)
```

it errors out with `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 11) are incompatible`.

I believe this to be an error in the shapes of my `x_train` and `y_train`, yet I'm not quite sure. I can see that the model (in the summary) is expecting an output of `(None, 11)`, so why is it outputting `(None, 1)` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is just that you need to use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function. That will take care of "expanding" the input labels automatically through one-hot encoding.

Comment: `out_len=1` would mean only 1 category. What needs to be done is to make `y_train` have the correct dimension.

Comment: You're right, my bad, I misread what you wrote. The problem here is just that you need to use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` as the loss function. That will take care of "expanding" the input labels automatically through one-hot encoding. Let me know if it works so I can edit my answer for future reference.

Comment: The labels are strings. @interjay Would my `y_train` have to be something like `(100, 11)`, where `100 = number of examples` and `11 = number of labels`? And if yes, I think the second dimension would be an array of 11 long, with a 1 in the position of the correct class label and 0's everywhere else?

Comment: @Devin Yes, that would work. I think `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` would also work as Massimo Zambelli says in the comment, if you provide the labels as integers.